# What would be the Pattern to display all existing Actors

Tags: akka

I programmed an Akka Application that realises Device Management. Every device is an Akka Actor and I implemented Akka Finite State Machine to control the lifecycle of Device, like FUNCTIONAL, BROKEN, IN_REPAIRS, RETIRED, etc...and I persist the devices with Akka Persistence to Cassandra.

Everything works like a dream but I have dilemma and I like to ask what would be pattern to deal with Akka.

I would nearly have 1 000 000 Devices, Akka is ideal to manage those single instances but how I implement that if user one to see all devices system and select one, change it is state...

I can't show it from Akka Journal table, I would not be able show anything other than persistenceId.

So how would you handle this dilemma.

My current plan, while all events coming to my system from Kafka, consume also these messages from Topic and redirect those to Solr/Elasticsearch, so I can index it some metadata with persistenceId, so user can select a Device to process with Akka Actor.

Do you have a better idea or how do you solve this idea?

Another option to save this information Cassandra to another Keyspace but for some reason I don't fancy it.....

Thx for answers...

Comment: Thx to the tips I got from the answer I successfully managed program Akka Projections with Elasticsearch, if anybody else needs to see, how it can be done, you can read it from my Blog https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 1):

Akka persistence is for managing Actor state so that it can be resilient with failures of application ( https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/).May not be optimal for using it for business cases. I understood that your requirement is to able to browse Actors in system. I see couple of options:

Option1:
Akka supports feature called named actors (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/addressing.html). In your case you have **device to Actor** as **one to one mapping**. So you can take advantage of this using with names actors feature. During the actors creation in actor system ,you apply this pattern so that all your actors in system are named with device ids.Now you can browse all your device ids (As this is your use case details, you can have searchable module using Solar/Elastic Search as you mentioned). Whenever browsing devices means you are browsing Actors in your system. You can use this named actor path to retrieve actor from system and do some actions.

Option2:
You can use monitoring tools for trace/browse actors in the application. Beyond your need it provides several other useful metrics.
https://www.lightbend.com/blog/akka-monitoring-telemetry
https://kamon.io/solutions/monitoring-for-akka/

Comment: I have created quick Actor model with spring boot project. it helps in understanding how retrieve actors by actor path and send messages to them. I used classic actor model, but we can use latest Actor API. https://github.com/muralimmd/AkkaNamedActorService

Answer (score 0):

Akka Persistence is heavily oriented to the Command-Query Responsibility Segregation style of implementing systems.  There are plenty of great outlines describing this pattern if you want more depth, but the broad idea is that you divide responsibility for changing data (the intent to change data being modeled through commands) from responsibility for querying data.  In some cases this responsibility carries through to separately deployed services, but it doesn't have to (the more separated, in terms of deployment/operations or development, the less coupled they are, so there's a cost/benefit tradeoff for where you want to be on the level-of-segregation spectrum).

Typically the portion of the system which is handling commands and deciding how (or even if) a given command updates state is often called the "write-side".  In your application, the FSM actors modeling the state of a device and persisting changes would be the write-side, and you seem to have that part down pat.

The portion handling the queries is, correspondingly, often called the "read-side", and one key benefit is that it can use a different data model than the write-side, up to and including using a different data store (e.g. Solr/Elasticsearch).

Since you're using Akka Persistence and event-sourcing (judging from mentioning the journal table), Akka Projections provides a good opinionated wrapper for publishing events from the write-side to Kafka for another service to update a Solr/Elasticsearch read-side with.  It does require (at least at this time) that your write-side tag events; with some effort you can do something similar by combining the `persistenceIds` and `eventsByPersistenceId` query streams to feed events from the write-side to Kafka without having to tag.

Note that when going down the CQRS path, you are generally committing to some level of eventual consistency between the write-side and the read-side.